# More information tab on product page missing after update to 2.3.5?

Tags: magento2.3, tabs

After updating from Magento 2.1 to **Magento 2.3.5**, I noticed that the More information tab is missing in the product page. The Details tab is still there.  I also checked the attributes which should be sown and they are set the same as in the old shop, where the tab is shown.

I disabled my custom theme and its still happening.

How could I the tab visible again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, there was an error in the template which renders the attributes. I solved the error and the tab showed up.